# ansible-playbook ignores '--check' parameter?

Tags: ansible, mikrotik

As testing a simple Ansible playbook

```yaml
--- 
- hosts: mikrotiks
  connection: network_cli 
  gather_facts: no 

  vars: 

    ansible_network_os: routeros 
    ansible_user: admin 

  tasks: 

  - name: Add Basic FW Rules 
    routeros_command: 
      commands: 
        - /ip firewall nat add chain=srcnat out-interface=ether1 action=masquerade
```

on my mikrotik router, I used the command with `--check` argument

```bash
ansible-playbook -i hosts mikrotik.yml --check
```

but it seems that tasks actually got executed.

```
PLAY [mikrotiks] **************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Add Basic FW Rules] **************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [192.168.1.82]

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************
192.168.1.82               : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

`ansible.cfg` file is the default configuration after fresh install.

Comment: Can you provide a description of the task? Which module is behind `TASK [Add Basic FW Rules]`? As well all parameter and configuration used? Without any further information this question is almost not answerable.

Comment: Hello @U880D and thanks for your answer !

My playbook yml file :
---
- hosts: mikrotiks
  connection: network_cli
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    ansible_network_os: routeros
    ansible_user: admin

  tasks:

   - name: Add Basic FW Rules
     routeros_command:
       commands:
         - /ip firewall nat add chain=srcnat out-interface=ether1 action=masquerade

Command used :
ansible-playbook -i hosts mikrotik.yml --check
And ansible.cfg file is the default configuration after fresh install.
I hope this is enough info ,thanks !

Comment: Do not use comments to provide necessary information to answer your question, moreover when it consists of large portion of code. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73163546/edit) your question and format the code inside a code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the documentation [`command` module – Run commands on remote devices running MikroTik RouterOS](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/routeros/command_module.html)

> *The module always indicates a (changed) status. You can use the `changed_when` task property to determine whether a command task actually resulted in a change or not.*

Since the module is part of the [community.routeros collection](https://galaxy.ansible.com/community/routeros?extIdCarryOver=true&sc_cid=701f2000001OH7YAAW) I had a short [look into the source](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.routeros) there and [found that is supporting `check_mode`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.routeros/blob/main/plugins/modules/command.py#L154) according

```py
    module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec=argument_spec,
                           supports_check_mode=True)
```

So you will need to follow up with [defining "changed"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-changed).